# Android - Dynamic TableLayout not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-tablelayout

I am trying to implement a HUD display to my cutsom keyboard. The HUD will contain pairs of key/value. I need to programatically create a TableLayout and draw it on my canvas. In order to do this, I am overriding the keyboardview onDraw() method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  // In the custom MyKeyboardView class
    MyHUD hud = new MyHUD(getContext());
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    hud.tl.draw(canvas);    //tl being the TableLayout to draw
}
```

MyHUD class:

```
public class MyHUD {

    public TableLayout tl;
    private MyData mData;

    public MyHUD(Context context) {

      TableRow.LayoutParams trParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      TableLayout.LayoutParams tlParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      tl = new TableLayout(context);
      tl.setLayoutParams(tlParams);

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
        tr.setId(100+i);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);

        TextView charTV = new TextView(context);
        charTV.setId(200+i);
        charTV.setText("Hello " + i);
        charTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        //charTV.setLayoutParams(trParams);
        tr.addView(charTV);

        TextView keyTV = new TextView(context);
        keyTV.setId(300+i);
        keyTV.setText("world " + i);
        keyTV.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        //keyTV.setLayoutParams(trParams);
        tr.addView(keyTV);

        tl.addView(tr, tlParams);   
      }       
   }
}
```

(Note that currently there is no data fetching, just a "Hello world" for test purposes).
I have commented out the TextView layouts, as seen on several other posts, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

---

Alternative option:

Instead of instanciating the TableLayout via a constructor, I have tried something like:

```
tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_hud);
```

Along with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:id="@+id/my_hud" >
</TableLayout>
```

The problem is that the findViewById method is undefined for my custom class.

Any idea why it is not properly drawing the TableLayout?

Comment: Hum I just thought about this: is it correct that I am using the keyboardview's context to instanciate the layout elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think it would be this simple, but here's what was missing:

```
    hud.tl.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    hud.tl.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

Now the TableLayout is properly drawn. Success.